# Timer continuing to countdown

Tags: android, timer, android-service

I have a problem with my timer service. Whenever I terminate the activity, the service restarts counting down instead of continuing to count down. I want it to continue counting down even though I terminate the app.

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
CountDownTimer timer;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private static final String TAG="com.timer";
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreate(){
    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onFinish(){

                }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    Log.i(TAG,"" + millisUntilFinished/1000);

                }
        };
        timer.start();
        }

    });

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy(){
    timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: return `START_NOT_STICKY` from `onStartCommand` and try..

Comment: Same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to terminate the timer, you should call the

```
timer.cancel();
```

Method in the onFinish() void.
That will terminate the timer.